# Capture specific columns from delimited file

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I am new to shell scripting and i need to create a shell script with the below condition.

The shell script should read the Inputfile.txt each line and take the first and sixth column in the file and create a new outputfile.txt

**Inputfile.txt**

```
123 | xyz | abc | abc | abc | 567

321 | xyz | abc | abc | abc | 765
```

**Outputfile.txt**

```
123 | 567

321 | 765
```

Comment: Where does the "765" come from?  Is it that you want the 11th field as well, or the last field?  

What have you tried?  In particular, try `cut`, or if you plan to do more operations on the columns, `awk`.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please consider editing this question so that its title is searchable and useful to other site visitors.

Answer (score 6):

Using a simple `cut` command should be enough:

```
cut -d "|" -f 1,6
```

Answer (score 2):

To capture the first and sixth items, and then print them out separated by vertical bars:

```
$ awk -F'|' '{print $1 "|" $6}' inputfile.txt 
123 | 567 321
```

The `-F'|'` tells `awk` to use the vertical bar as the field separator on the input file.

To save the above output in `outputfile.txt`, use redirection:

```
$ awk -F'|' '{print $1 "|" $6}' inputfile.txt >outputfile.txt
```

Alternatively, the same result can be achieved by setting `awk`'s output field separator (`OFS`) to a vertical bar:

```
$ awk -F'|' 'BEGIN{OFS="|"} {print $1,$6}' inputfile.txt >outputfile.txt
```

Comment: You could use awk's `OFS` instead of manually reinserting the pipes. `awk 'BEGIN{FS="|";OFS="|"} {print $1,$6}'`

Comment: @kojiro OK.  I added that option.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use any tools then here is a way to get first and last elements in `bash`:

```
$ cat inputfile.txt 
123 | xyz | abc | abc | abc | 567
321 | xyz | abc | abc | abc | 765
```

```
$ while IFS="|" read -ra line; do 
    echo "${line[0]}|${line[${#line[@]}-1]}"
done < inputfile.txt 
123 | 567
321 | 765
```

You can use literal subscripts too, so instead of `${line[${#line[@]}-1]}` you can do `${line[5]}`.

Comment: bash is still a tool…

Answer (score 0):

you can use `awk` as well:

```
awk  '{print $1, $10, $11}' input.txt
```

(OR)

```
awk -F'|' '{print $1 "|" $6  $11}' input.txt
```

(OR)

```
awk '{print $1, $11}' input.txt
```

(OR)

You can simply use `cut` command:

```
cut -d"|" -f 1,6
```

(OR)

Using `sed`:

```
sed 's/|.*|/|/' input.txt
```

Also with `grep`...But I am not that familiar with it yet :)

**Also: @anubhava told me:**

```
awk -F '[| ]+' '{print $1, $NF}' OFS=' | ' input.txt
```

(OR)

```
while IFS=' | ' read -a arr
    echo "${arr[0]} | ${arr[@]:(-1)}"
done < input.txt
```

Comment: @user3326101 you can accept and upvote my answer to tell this is solved